# Работа с типами C#

Tags: c#, типы

Нужна помощь в работе с типами.
У меня есть переменная myField, мне нужно ее преобразовать в тип, который я не должен знать.
То есть нужен механизм который делал бы примерно вот так:

```
Type type = typeof(AnyNotMyClass); //какой класс будет в скобках я не знаю
var field = (type) myField; //допустим преобразование будет возможным
```

Возможно ли такое вобще делать в c# ?

Comment: Возможно. В какой момент и как вы узнаёте тип для приведения?

Comment: Попробуйте генерики

Comment: Да, ам может быть один из трех типов. Я могу просто преобразовывать по очереди в каждый, но это работает пока типов 3, если их станет 20 так уже не получится делать.

Comment: Используйте object тип + (каст к нужному, или рефлексия)

Comment: А что вы будете делать с объектом этого типа дальше? Если вы не знаете его на этапе компиляции, вы не можете вызвать его методы или обратиться к его свойствам.

Answer (score 1):

Написанный код не висит в воздухе, поэтому где-то до этого на вход метода передаётся переменная с типом Type

```
void Main()
{
    Test(typeof(string));
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public void Test(Type t)
{
        Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Само приведение делается двумя способами (см. подробнее на [en so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47134147/5752652)): через Convert или Generic-метод.

```
public static void method1(Type convertTo, object toBeConverted)
{
    var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(toBeConverted, convertTo);
}

public static void method2<TConvert>(object toBeConverted)
{
    var convertedValue = (TConvert)toBeConverted;
}
```

И как бы вы не говорили, что не знаете, какой это будет тип -- нужно уточнить, откуда вы узнаёте тип и в какой момент.

Comment: У меня есть таблица в которой DataSource это BindingList<dynamic> source. В момент инициализации  происходит source.Add (new MyClass ...), кроме MyClass там может быть MyClass1 или MyClass2. Я не зкаю какой именно класс там будет использоватся.

Comment: Есть какой нибудь метод, как Convert.ChangeType, только что бы он возвращает тип данных, который указан вторым аргументом ?

Comment: @TitovS.P., всё это должно было быть в вашем вопросе. У ваших классов есть что нибудь общее? Хотя бы интерфейс?

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. Ковариантность тут не пройдет, потому что я НЕ ЗНАЮ в какой тим мне делать upcast. Мне нужно делать upcast в тот тип данных, который приходит как аргумент метода Type type;